# Qual é a finalidade da palavra-chave "export"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, característica-linguagem, export

Criei um [projeto em Angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) para iniciar minha aprendizagem e atualmente estou usando TypeScript para fazer o App. No entanto, uma dúvida surgiu em relação a palavra-chave `export` (isso se realmente for uma palavra-chave).

Usei ela para criar uma classe e um *array*.

#### Classe:

```
export class Anime {
    id: number;
    titulo: string;
    imagem: string;
}
```

#### Array:

```
export const ANIMES: Anime[] = [
    { id: 1, titulo: 'Tate no Yuusha no Nariagari', imagem: 'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/1068/97169.jpg' },
    { id: 2, titulo: 'Yakusoku no Neverland', imagem: 'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/1125/96929.jpg' },
    { id: 2, titulo: 'Youjo Senki', imagem: 'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/5/82890.jpg' }
];
```

Veja que esta palavra é usada em duas ocasiões. Sendo assim, é neste ponto que surgem minhas dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a finalidade da palavra-chave `export`?
2. Por que usar ela para criar *arrays* ou classes?
3. Ela tem alguma relação com o Angular em si?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Qual é a finalidade da palavra-chave `export`?

Conhece `public` de outras linguagens? Basicamente é isso. Por alguma razão o JavaScript escolheu usar isso, e o TypeScript o adotou, antes do JS oficializar, para determinar que aquele membro pode ser acessado fora daquele módulo, então qualquer membro marcado assim pode ser importado para seu código de consumo, os demais não podem, só são visíveis dentro do próprio módulo. Só estamos falando de membros de módulos, não de classes. Lembrando que se estiver fora de um módulo o arquivo acaba funcionando como um módulo próprio que será considerado exportado.

Existe o `public` também que é apenas um controle de acesso dos membros de classe, só que o padrão é público e ele acaba sendo opcional ( seu `id`, `titulo` e `imagem` já são públicos. Acabaram separando essas coisas em duas palavras-chave, diferente de outras linguagens.

> Por que usar ela para criar *arrays* ou classes?

Na verdade pode ser usada em qualquer declaração de membros de um módulo, não tem nada de especial para esses fins. Seus exemplos só dizem que a classe pode ser acessada, portanto instanciada, por toda aplicação, assim como esse *array*.

> Ela tem alguma relação com o Angular em si?

Não.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Conceptual.md).