# Qual é a diferença entre export e export default?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Qual é a diferença entre se utilizar a palavra reservada `export` e `export default`. Por exemplo:

```
export class Helper { } 

export default class Helper { }
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360161/27190

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ambos comandos são utilizados para criar módulos, e permitir que ao importar em outro arquivo, possa ser utilizado tudo que há naquele módulo.

A principal diferença é, como o próprio nome sugere (`default`), o `export default` é o membro (class, variável, const, etc) se expõe por padrão naquele módulo e, portanto, **só pode haver um membro padrão sendo exportado por módulo**.

Qual a vantagem disso? Diferente de um export explícito ou nomeado, o default não precisa ser referenciado com o mesmo nome ao ser importado.

Pegando o exemplo da pergunta:
`export default class Helper { }`

Isso poderia ser importado assim:

```
import abobrinha from 'nome-do-module';
var a = new abobrinha();
```

Isso é possível pois como é o default daquele módulo, pode-se importar com qualquer nome que sempre vai referenciar aquele membro.

Já o export nomeado, tem de ser importado exatamente com o mesmo nome, por permitir exportar vários membros dentro de um mesmo módulo, pois seria impossível saber qual membro desejamos usar.

Para ilustrar, imagine esse módulo exportado:

```
export class Helper { } 
export class Logger { }
```

Ao importar, não poderia usar outro nome assim, pois não seria possível saber de qual membro estamos nos referindo:

```
import abobrinha from 'nome-do-module';
```

Obrigatoriamente deve-se seguir os nomes com os quais foram exportados:

```
import { Helper, Logger} from 'nome-do-module';
```

Mais detalhes aqui: [mozilla/export](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Comment: quando eu utilizo export default nenhum membro fica exporto certo? Então esse e o motivo de o export default nao expor nenhuma propriedade da minha exportação ? tipo com export consigo acessar algum metodo da minha classe, já com export default não.

Comment: sim fica exposto, é um *export* afinal, mas como ele é default só pode exportar um membro por módulo dessa forma

Comment: inclusive como não é necessário nome, podia exportar uma function anônima até: `export default function () { algum código };`

Comment: o nome do import (export default é simbolico neste caso) uma referencia do meu arquivo, certo

Comment: isso, seria como "importa ai o que tiver nesse arquivo com esse nome" :)

Comment: Então esse e o motivo de eu não conseguir acessar um metodo estatico com export default, so dando new